# ESRI API for BAO reports in Python

Tags: python, rest, soap, arcgis, esri

Currently we use [ESRI's Business Analyst Online (BAO)](http://bao.arcgis.com) to create demographic reports based on geospatial inputs (3-mile ring around an address, or within a city's boundaries, etc.).  These are generally output from the point and click web application as PDF or Excel files.

I'm trying to automate the process of retrieving those reports from ESRI BAO.  I have installed the Python 3.5+ package `arcgis` following instructions found [here](https://developers.arcgis.com/python/guide/install-and-set-up/#Install-using-Conda).  This seems to get me started with the ArcGIS functionality, but I don't see any API functionality for the BAO toolset.  Is there another API package I should be downloading?  Or is there documentation on a REST/SOAP API I can call from Python?  I've looked over the [documentation](https://developers.arcgis.com/documentation/), but if there's something there about what I'm trying to do I haven't found it.

Has anybody tried to do this before and been successful?  Let me know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After starting trials for several ArcGIS services I found that [ArcGIS Online](http://www.esri.com/software/arcgis/arcgisonline) provides access to ESRI's REST API.  As of today, once you've signed up (either paying or with a trial) you can navigate to the [ArcGIS GeoEnrichment Service Documentation](https://developers.arcgis.com/rest/geoenrichment/api-reference/geoenrichment-service-overview.htm).  That documentation tells you everything you need to know about how to access the same reports you would find in ESRI BAO, but through a REST API.